# Why is $LG(n) \cong U(n)/O(n)$?

Tags: symplectic-linear-algebra, homogeneous-spaces

Let $LG(n)$ be a Lagrangian Grassmanian manifold. That is, $LG(n)$ is the set of Lagrangian subspaces of a symplectic vector space of dimension $2n$.

Why can $LG(n)$ be identified with $U(n)/O(n)$?

Here $U(n)$ and $O(n)$ are unitary and orthogonal groups respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The unitary group acts transitively on $\operatorname{LG}(n)$ i.e. there is a unitary action that can take any element of $\operatorname{LG}(n)$ to any other.

Considering a group $G$ acting on a manifold $X$ there is a homeomorphism:
\begin{equation}
f: \frac{G}{G_x} \leftrightarrow X 
\end{equation}
where $G_x$ is the isotropy group of some $x \in X$.

For any $p \in \operatorname{LG}(n)$ the isotropy group is $\operatorname{O}(n)$. Therefore $\operatorname{LG}(n)$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{U}(n)/\operatorname{O}(n)$.

The general theorem is named *Homogeneous Space Characterisation Theorem* in Lee's 'Introduction to Smooth Manifolds'. The specific theorem for Lagrangian Grassmannians was found in a chapter of de Gosson's book, 'Symplectic Methods in Harmonic Analysis and in Mathematical Physics':
webzoom.freewebs.com/cvdegosson/symplectic%20group.pdf

Comment: In fact the manifolds are diffeomorphic. And there exists a special kid of diffeomorphism called an equivariant diffeomorphism between them.